# get parent element attribute value

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

this is my xml document:-

```
<root>
    <child_1 entity_id = "1" value="india">
        <child_2 entity_id = "2" value="gujarat">
            <child_3 entity_id = "3" value="Ahemdabad"/>
            <child_4 entity_id = "4" value="Surat"/>
            <child_5 entity_id = "5" value="Rajkot"/>           
        </child_2>
    </child_1>
</root>
```

this is my javascript html code:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var xml;
        var ind_sex;
        $.get(
        "code.xml",
        null,
        function (data) {
            xml = data;
        },
        "xml"
    );
        function get_list() {
            var city = $('#name').val();
            alert(city);
            var xPath = '//*[@value = "city"]' + 
                            '/../../@value';

          var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath, xml.documentElement, null,
                XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
            var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            var str = '';
            while (thisNode) {
                if (str) {
                    str += ', ';
                }
                str += thisNode.textContent;
                thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            }

            $("#result").text(str);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="name"></input>
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="get_list()">
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here i am try to input in textbox city name if its match on my xml file then its return me there country name. 
i dont get any error but not getting result.
i think problem in my xPath pleasae help me out of this.

Comment: You apparently replaced your question with something completely different after someone tried answering it. Why not just start a new question?

Comment: I completely agree with @Barmar. It is not recommendable to completely change the question just on the day before the deadline. Please, ask a *new* question, if you have a new problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use**:

```
var xPath = '//*[@value = "' + city + '"]/../../@value';
```

**An equivalent expression is**:

```
var xPath = '//*[*/*[@value = "' + city +  ']]/@value';
```

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev They're not equivalent, IMO. I'd rather use the second version as it doesn't require two way tree walking (also toward the root). I'm not sure if I could find any docs again, but something whispers that older implementations of xpath engines had issues with it. Also I'm not quite sure if you really mean using asterix. Shouldn't dots go therein, like `var xPath = '//.[./.[@value = "' + city +  ']]/@value';`? Compare [this](http://www.mulberrytech.com/quickref/XSLT_1quickref-v2.pdf).

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński, Yes, thesy are equivalent -- they select exactly the same attributes. And ("asterisk") `/*` means (on the child axis) any *element* child of the context node. Similarly, `//*` means any descendent element of the context node. And any compliant XPath implementation must support both expressions. On the other side `//.` means any *node* (not only element node) that is the context node or a descendent of the context node.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, lists don't work like that... they're variables associated with a given value, so it's more like:

`list($a, $b, $c) = [1, 2, 3];`

Anyway, why don't you take a look at  the 'Lists' section in the [phpredis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis#lists) page? It's one of the recommended PHP clients for Redis, and its examples are quite clear